# Problem with plotting a polygon with ggplot + osmdata

Tags: r, ggplot2, openstreetmap, osmdata

I have a problem working with plotting a polygon obtained by osmdata.
First, I get the polygon of the object using this code

```
library(osmdata)
loespejo_mersal <- opq_osm_id (type = "way", id = 39259197)%>%
opq_string () %>%
osmdata_sf ()
```

And i got the data without problem, but when I need to plot in a certain limit, I got the error.

```
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = loespejo_mersal$osm_polygons,
          inherit.aes = FALSE,
          fill = "red",
          size = .1,
          alpha = .5)+
  coord_sf(xlim= c(-70.71, -70.67),
           ylim = c(-33.54, -33.50),
           expand = FALSE)+
  labs(title = "TEST Mersan")

Warning message:
In st_cast.GEOMETRYCOLLECTION(X[[i]], ...) :
  only first part of geometrycollection is retained
```

But if i change the limits, I don't have problems.

```
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = loespejo_mersal$osm_polygons,
          inherit.aes = FALSE,
          fill = "red",
          size = .1,
          alpha = .5)+
  coord_sf(xlim= c(-70.75, -70.65),
           ylim = c(-33.6, -33.5),
           expand = FALSE)+
  labs(title = "TEST Mersan")
```

I'm trying to understand the error, but I'm stuck :(

Answer (score 0):

That's because `xlim`, `ylim` doesn't cover the whole bounding box of your polygon. To check it we will use `sf` library:

```r
library(osmdata)
library(ggplot2)
library(sf)

loespejo_mersal <- opq_osm_id (type = "way", id = 39259197)%>%
  opq_string () %>%
  osmdata_sf ()

lmbbox <- st_bbox(st_as_sf(loespejo_mersal$osm_polygons))
lmbbox
#>      xmin      ymin      xmax      ymax 
#> -70.70874 -33.55168 -70.68260 -33.52892
```

Let's provide set up `xlim`, `ylim` for whole area of bounding box:

```
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = loespejo_mersal$osm_polygons,
          inherit.aes = FALSE,
          fill = "red",
          size = .1,
          alpha = .5)+
  coord_sf(xlim= c(lmbbox[1], lmbbox[3]),
           ylim = c(lmbbox[2], lmbbox[4]),
           expand = FALSE)+
  labs(title = "TEST Mersan")
```

[image]

And just to confirm, it's related to `ggplot` (and how it treats geometries), we can use simple `plot`:

```r
plot(loespejo_mersal$osm_polygons$geometry, col="darkgreen")
```

[image]

There was similar question: [Error when plotting latitude and longitude points on US map in RStudio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69869786/error-when-plotting-latitude-and-longitude-points-on-us-map-in-rstudio). It can be related to projection, because a simple reprojection to EPSG:3857 and ggplotting went smoothly:

```
b<- st_transform(a, crs = "EPSG:3857")
st_bbox(b)
#>     xmin     ymin     xmax     ymax 
#> -7871261 -3968762 -7868351 -3965722

ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = b,
          inherit.aes = FALSE,
          fill = "red",
          size = .1,
          alpha = .5) +
  coord_sf(xlim= c(-7871400, -7868000),
         ylim = c(-3967762, -3966722),
         expand = FALSE)+
  labs(title = "TEST Mersan")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-02-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>